# Why is objc_duplicateClass marked "Do not call this function yourself"

Tags: objective-c

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/1418645-objc_duplicateclass) for `objc_duplicateClass` reads simply

> Used by Foundation's Key-Value Observing. Do not call this function yourself.

with no elaboration or explanation. I read the [source](https://github.com/opensource-apple/objc4/blob/cd5e62a5597ea7a31dccef089317abb3a661c154/runtime/objc-runtime-new.mm), but didn't see anything in it that that gave me any indication for why you shouldn't call it, except a few theories; except that `load` and `initialize` don't get called for classes created by `objc_duplicateClass`?

It seems like you could produce pretty much the same effect by calling `objc_allocateClassPair` with no extra bytes for additional ivars, and then immediately registering it. So what's special about `objc_duplicateClass`? Or, to rephrase the question, if, hypothetically, I wanted to build KVO, or something very similar, on top of the objc runtime, would it be safe to to use `objc_duplicateClass`?

Comment: You should not be using it because it's an internal function that can change or be removed.

Comment: @Sulthan It is not internal, since it is documented. However, every method or function of the system libs can change.

Answer (score 1):

`objc_duplicateClass` does pretty much what it says on the tin: it produces a new class which is a copy of the class that you give it. This includes copying the methods that the old class had, all of its metadata bits, and even its metaclass.

You couldn't recreate this behavior with `objc_allocateClassPair` because `objc_allocateClassPair` registers a new metaclass for the class you create, among other things like initializing the class — it is meant to create a *new* class. `objc_duplicateClass` creates a copy; the "new" class is not initialized any further and does not get a new metaclass because the original one already did.

As for why `objc_duplicateClass` is documented the way that it is: to discourage its use. `objc_duplicateClass` has some rare use cases, and will almost never be what you want. If you find a need for it, use it, but keep in mind that there are subtleties to the implementation you may not be aware of.

Comment: Can you give an example, in which rare use case it is necessary to use that function and what exactly are the subtleties?

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad The most prominent use case is KVO, which is why it exists. When adding an observer to an object, KVO duplicates the class and changes the object's isa to point to the duplicated class. All existing methods forward through the existing dispatch tables, but any observed properties can have their implementations changed in this class copy without affecting the old "real" class. This is significantly faster than generating a new class (to do, and for dispatching method calls), doesn't break compatibility since the new class _is_ the old class, for most intents.

Comment: You don't _have_ to do it this way — there is no necessity here. But duplicating the class in-place silently allows for efficient implementation with minimal breakage...

Comment: I cannot see, why this is this significantly faster, because creating a nearly empty new class reduces the work to do at class creation. Moreover for dispatching the methods will be in the cache extremely fast. The changed implementation is simply a overwritten implementation in the subclass. (You have to invoke the base implementation in either case.) For the observed properties dispatching is irrelevant, because the costs of even creating the objects for the observer method will have costs that are incredible higher.

Comment: KVO is a prominent use case? On my Mac the resulting class *is* a subclass of the original class. Go ahead and try it. So either duplication means subclassing, what makes duplication meaningless as I said, or subclassing instead of duplication is used, what makes duplication meaningless as I said. And I really wonder, which performance advantage do we get from duplication over subclassing, when subclassing is used.

Comment: I had a look at the source: Duplication *is* subclassing. And there is completely nothing "in place", what would not work for the simple reason, that observing one *instance* of a class must not change anything to the class.

Comment: Let's get off the KVO example then — I am likely wrong about this, and the implementation has changed since I last looked. Another prominent use-case where `objc_duplicateClass` _is_ still used is with `NSZombie` objects; when an instance of a class is deallocated, the class is duplicated and the isa is set to point to the new class. Could this be done with `objc_allocateClassPair`? Yes. But for efficiency, `objc_duplicateClass` can be used instead.

Comment: I also don't agree that duplication is subclassing, though. What in the source leads you to that conclusion? A duplicate `A2` of a class `A1` does not inherit from `A1`; it inherits from `A1`'s superclass, just like `A1` does.

Comment: Register an observation and print out the class hierarchy using the RTE. KVO is using subclassing for years.

Comment: You are right: I misread the code of duplicateClass. However, this does not change anything that observation uses subclassing.

Comment: In the case of KVO, subclassing must be used for Swift compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Even I marked the Q as opinion based, I'd like to try an answer:

A. Such a statement usually marks a function (or whatever) to be obsolete and is planned to be removed in future.

B. Indeed, there is no reason for this function. I do not agree with your statement, that registering a new class with zero extra bytes would do the job. because maybe there are extra bytes and you have to copy all instance var descriptions and methods manually.

However, I had to deal with such situations as KVO in the past. I have never used `objc_duplicateClass()`, because t is much easier and akin of cleaner to create a subclass and then make the instance a member of that subclass. You can do isa-swizzling for that calling `object_setClass(id object, Class cls)`.

Think of a situation, obviously it is yours, that another technology wants to do something like KVO, too. Duplicating a class using `objc_duplicateClass()` takes not part on future dynamic changes of the original class. Maybe a method is added to it. A duplication would not add this method, too.

So `objc_duplicateClass()` is not useful and a bad approach.

Comment: I don't thing "there is no reason for this function" is correct. There is a reason it exists — to duplicate a class exactly.

Comment: @ItaiFerber There is no reason to duplicate a class as explained in my post.

Comment: Just because you don't _have_ to doesn't mean there aren't benefits to doing so. By allocating a new class and calling `object_setClass`, anyone looking at the object's class sees that new class. This breaks anyone using `-isMemberOfClass:`, for instance. There are drawbacks to both methods, but neither is necessarily "right".

Comment: It is also not true that dynamic changes to the class do not reflect through the duplicated class — they do, and the runtime is smart enough to forward those changes. You can test this yourself: add a method to the original class of a now observed object, then call the method on the object with the duplicate class. It will work just fine.

Comment: This is wrong: Observing a class *is* visible from outside. Simply try to get the class name: using `class_getName(object_getClass(object))`: `NSKVONotifying_className`. Even it is duplicated it *is* a new class. `isMemberOfClass:` is a method and can easily overwritten by the subclass.

Comment: Maybe this is the reason, why at least on my Mac a bound object *actually have a class* that is a subclass of the original class.

Comment: I'm wondering what is different between our testing strategies, because I don't see that behavior at all on my machine. After I add an observer to an object, its class does not change to an `NSKVONotifiying_` class, but I am certainly willing to admit that my testing strategy is flawed somehow, and I am incorrect — curious to see your code, though. :)

Comment: Likely you use Cocoa methods to check for the class. Use the RTE.